# Supported Arduino functions on ATTinyCore by SpenceKonde

Tags: arduino, attiny

I've just discovered the ATtiny84/85 chips and have ordered a few to use in some projects. I've looked high and low for all the support it has for programming through the Arduino IDE and Uno and have come across high-low tech's website and the supported arduino functions in that core.

Then I came across SpenceKonde's ATTinyCore which is another highly regarded core for the ATTiny series. The problem is that I can't find any information as to what classic Arduino functions this core supports. I mean like a list. I'm sure the basic functions are supported but how about using sleep mode / low power mode and a few other things. Is everything in the Arduino.h library supported?

Sorry if this is a silly question but a little help would be much appreciated.

Comment: SpenceKonde a.k.a. DrAzzy is active on forum.arduino.cc. even online right now

Comment: Scrambling to create Arduino forum account right NOW. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted DrAzzy a.k.a Spence Konde on the Arduino Forum regarding this matter and I'm going to quote his reply to me down below.

> ATTinyCore (and my other cores) implements all of the standard Arduino API functions that are logically coherent for the hardware in question. Everything should work, even the stuff that I think is a dumb idea (eg, SerialEvent, yield()) - if it doesn't, it should be reported to me as a bug. There are only a few places where I knowingly departed from the official Arduino behavior
>
> Stuff that isn't arduino API, like the stuff that's included with avrlibc, has no dependence on the core whatsoever. If the hardware supports it, those libraries should work. If it fails to compile with the library (or a specific call in the library) in the sketch (generally giving either a #error saying it's unsupported, or an "undefined reference" to a register or bit name - actually calling it at a sensible time or uploading and verifying it behaves the way you want is usually unnecessary)

Hope this helps you guys. Thanks again to Spence Konde (DrAzzy) for the amazing ATTinyCore and his help in this matter.